# How to duplicate a row in the same table in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I know I am supposed to create a temporary table based on an existing row, remove the id and then insert an new row in my "real" table based on the temporary table. But it does not work in my prestashop.

```
$id = 4;
$createTemp = Db::getInstance()->Execute('CREATE TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id="'.$id.'"');
$updateTemp = Db::getInstance()->Execute('UPDATE temp_table SET id=NULL');
$insertQuery = Db::getInstance()->Execute('INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM temp_table');
$deleteTemp = Db::getInstance()->Execute('DROP TABLE temp_table');
```

If I make a var_dump of those I always get a `FALSE`. I tried to make the `select` only in a query and it does work so my `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id="'.$id.'"` is correct.

I need to be able to duplicate a row and I could'nt find another/a better way to do so. What do I have to change in my code to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

If source data is OK your code should work,
I would enable Prestashop **mode_dev** so you can see the query errors on-screen for better debug.

Since you're working with Prestashop - maybe your "my_table" id is not called id but something different like "id_product" ?

If this is the case, first create will fail and all other queries will fail consequently.

Comment: I wrote "my_table" and "id" as examples but in my code I adapted it. And the select in my first query works fine...

Comment: maybe the db user you are using for prestashop has privilege limitations in mysql and cannot create new tables ?